# Sum of values based on specific field name or Sum of values based on specific field names from different layers using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arctoolbox, summarizing, arcgis-10.7

I am looking for a way to sum the numerical values contained in a layer file based on a specific field name in ArcGIS 10.7

Let's say that I have a polygon shapefile that contains region names and the number of inhabitants. I would like to sum the number of inhabitants per region name to then illustrate population density on the map.

Is there any tool or code in ArcGIS that can generate a shapefile (not a dbase or a table) where starting from the first example (in the image) I can obtain the attribute table as in the final results?

Alternatively, is it possible to obtain the same results starting from 2 different layers?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If layers have the same fields and the values are same as in your example then, merge those layers. Then `dissolve` on the Region field. If it is just one layer, run `dissolve`

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm

Dissolve field is the Region in your case.

Statistics: put your field with MAX/SUM whatever suits your needs.

After that you will have new layer, with SUMmed column and you can plot it as you like

If they have different field names. Create common fields, with same structure. Merge them and run `dissolve` again

Comment: Hi Jan, Thank you so much, I forgot that dissolve field could do that!